# Dyndns with Ubuntu-Core

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, nextcloud

i want to connect my Nextcloud-Box with a DynDns Service, but my Router doesn't support ip updating for that service, so I have to do it with my raspberry, but I don't know how, since I can't install ddclient with snap as its not available in the snap-store. Does anyone have another solution?
Thank you in Advance :D
P.S my service is not no-ip, so I dont think that I can use their application.

Comment: I started a [thread](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/dynamic-dns-client-snap-suggestion/1499) over on the [Snapcraft Forum](https://forum.snapcraft.io/) to see if someone might be up for the challenge, because I didn't see a dyndns client in the repo, and this is such a great idea.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think if nothing comes up i just install a "normal" Version and install Nextcloud and ddclient manually, respectively with apt-get. It's a shame though, because basically snap isn't bad at all.